# What is the simplest way to show images in slideshow?

Tags: android, image, android-viewpager, slideshow

I have a `List` of URLs that I would like to load into a slideshow using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). I just want something that will handle the swiping left/right, and lets me do something like this to populate the image:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.img);
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrls.get(position), imageView);
```

I have looked at `ViewPager`, but it's only in the support libraries and looks overly complicated for what I want to do. What's the easiest way to get this done? I am targeting KitKat and above.

Comment: try to check out this tut, http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

Comment: @UMESH0492, thank you. That was the simplest tutorial I have seen so far, and I've got it working. If you would like to submit an answer, I will select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to check out this tut, http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

Thanks and you would find many other good tuts on android hive.
You may also refer http://www.androidexample.com for other tuts.